# WiFi Direct and VPN

Tags: windows, uwp, network-programming

I have an application that controls a camera over a WiFi direct connection. It connects to the camera by enumerating available networks with NetworkAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks and then calling NetworkAdapter.ConnectAsync to connect.
This works fine on most systems. On some systems, however there appears to be a conflict with installed VPNs. If a VPN is installed on the system, sometimes after connection network requests to specific IP addresses on the WiFi direct device fail to be routed correctly. (requests are always to IP addresses on this device). The requests appear to be routed improperly by the VPN and fail to resolve. The really odd thing is that this only happens sometimes. I can issue the same request five times in a row, and 4 of them might fail, but one succeed.

Question - how to temporarily disable the VPN, or at least stop it from interfering with the routing of requests for this particular connection?

There doesn't appear to be anything on the NetworkAdapter class about dealing with routing or VPN.
I've looked at the VPN namespace
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn.vpndomainnameinfo
But that appears to be mainly about setting up VPNs on the device and requires special store permissions to use.
The WiFiDirectDevice class appears to be about setting up a WiFiDirect connection to the hosting device, not connecting to another device.

Answer (score 0):

First think to check here would be to see if there is a VPN route conflict here. you can do this by running the following command from a command prompt

```
route print -4
```

This will print out the routes in a format like

```
Interface List
 23...ee 15 36 22 ea 9b ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
  2...ee 15 36 41 e5 b6 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
 52...........................MSIT AutoVPN
 17...b6 ae 2b c4 41 b4 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 11...b6 ae 2b c4 44 b4 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 14...b4 ae 2b c4 40 b5 ......Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller
  9...b4 ae 2b c4 40 b6 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.100     35
```

Look for the routes marked to your VPN interface and see if it lies within the routes you are trying to reach. You can then add a more specific route using route.exe Add command for the IP address you are trying to connect to

Comment: Thanks - that helps diagnose the issue for me, but doesn't help me resolve it from code. I need a way to detect the issue and correct it from within a UWP app. The existing classes and methods don't appear to offer any way to detect the routing issue or correct it.

Comment: What was the result of the Diagnosis, is there a route conflict ? Also How are you actually communicating over the WiFi direct interface, are you using StreamSockets or some other API? can you share that as well ?

Comment: It shows that everything is being routed through the VPN even though I'm not connected to that network any more. If I leave it sitting for several minutes, eventually the VPN detects that it shouldn't be active any more and things get routed correctly, but I don't want my app users to have to wait several minutes just to connect. I'm using standard HttpWebRequest to make requests on this network. UDP requests seem to get routed correctly.